# Cannot edit QGIS project in QField (save to PostgreSQL db)

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qfield, log

I struggle to edit my project in QField on a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 2. The general idea would be to **create and edit points in the field and save them in a PostgreSQL db (offline and online).**

What I did so far is the following:

1. I created a portable project in QGIS (My project consists of a simple WMS base map and a "mask" that opens when creating a new point asking for the attributes of that point. This layer's source is the postgresql db. Editing and saving to the database works in the QGIS project.)
2. Exported the project via Qfield sync as a package for QField
3. Saved the package on the tablet under:
   internaldata/Android/Data/ch.opemgis.qfield
4. Opened the project in QField on the tablet

-> The project will distplay perfectly but is **not editable**.

The **Log-message** says everywhere that the connection to database failed (PostGIS) and that editing cannot be started (QField).

To test this error, I set the layer in the QField sync project configuration to offline editing (so that it won't search for a db connection online). However, the log stays the same. This is why I believe that not being able to edit anything is an error that is based on some database connection mistake.

Comment: Try this: in QGIS, when you create your PostGIS connection to load the layers, tick Store in the credentials : https://i.imgur.com/kNIZlOr.png

Comment: thx! I set up the project with a new layer having the credentials stored, however that still does not work (gives me the exact same log).

Comment: Just to make sure: the database is really online and not on a PG installed on your computer in localhost ?

Comment: And is SSL disabled in your PG connection ? see here the definition of a connection that works (it's the postgis online example project of QField) : https://i.imgur.com/l6IeSBC.png

Comment: Yes, the data base is online (not local) and SSL is disabled. I just tried the QField example by creating a new PG layer as you said. Weirdly, the log-message still shows exacly the same and says that it is unable to connect to my db (even though this is the demo db from QField). It seems that the log does not refresh.

Comment: Also, I just tried the same demo project (pre-installed on QField) on the samsung tablet and on my huawei phone. On my phone I could create new points, whereas on the tablet I could not edit at all (and it showed the same old log).

Comment: Same version of QField and Android on the phone and tablet ?

Comment: Now it's working on the tablet too! I didn't have the latest QField-version on the tablet (one version older than the newest). After the update, it's working - Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ok cool :) Just to document the complete workflow, did you have to store the credentials in the project like I showed in the first screenshot or was it not needed ?

Comment: Yes, I needed to store the credentials too.

Comment: Hi all, i have the same issue of this discussion, that is the connection to database failed (PostGIS) in QField in my smartphone Android; so i cannot view the layer Postgis on the map. The database Postgresql is installed and connected in my laptop, SSL is disabled, the QGis project has the DB credentials stored and i exported the project via Qfield sync as a package for QField (setting "no action" for the postgis). Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!